# Purpose of upgrading php version on hosting

Tags: php, hosting

Can anyone explain the purpose of upgrading php version from 5.2 to 5.5. Today I got a mail from my hosting provider saying:

"You are using version 5.2 of the scripting language PHP. This version is neither up to date, nor has it been developed any further by the PHP community since January 2011. We therefore recommend to update to the current PHP version 5.5."

I have a basic php website on that hosting. Should I update?

Can anyone explain the advantages of upgrading the version? Also disadvantages of my current version 5.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, my suggestion is it depends. The new versions are always safe and secure. But sometimes a new version will cause most of your old codes to not working (in case your website has very old coding practices.) So its better to try it at your local environment!

Good Luck.

Here is a nice and a useful blog post from phpclasses.org. This talks about upgrade to php 5.4, but still valid for 5.5 as it speaks generally.

Read More at : http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/173-PHP-54-Features-Shall-you-Upgrade-to-the-newer-PHP-Version.html

Briefly:

**Shall I Upgrade to PHP 5.4?**

By now you may be wondering if it is worth to upgrade to PHP 5.4. Here is some advice that you may want to consider. Some of the recommendations are so obvious, that maybe they do not really need to be given, but they are given anyway so you be certain that this is just common sense.

**No, if you do not really need the new features**

It is basic common sense to never change the team that is winning. If you looked at PHP 5.4 features and did not see anything you may be interested in using, simply do not bother to upgrade.

If you insist just because you want to ride on the top of the latest wave, chances are that your PHP code may break due to changes that you were not aware.

**No, if you need unsupported extensions**

If you need some extensions that do not come built-in PHP, like for instance a caching extension as mentioned above, chances are that such extensions may not yet be ready for this new version.

So, it is advised to not upgrade at least until such extensions are upgraded to work with PHP 5.4, or maybe do not upgrade at all until there are replacement extensions for the same purposes.

Comment: +1 for the explanation and the link for reference.

Comment: -1 for _No, if you do not really need the new features_. :)

Comment: @user3571366 1. You should always upgrade your app to the latest version of the selected platform (that increases app life-cycle). 2. There's been quite big improvements from 5.2 to 5.4 that are not visible for user-land.